# Using Vue JS 2, firebase returned data object not defined on instance but referenced during render

Tags: firebase, vuejs2

I'm working through the Vue tutorial at https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/vue-js-2-firebase-e4b2479e35a8.  I can post new data to firebase but I'm not getting any returned data.

I see this error in the console:

> vue.esm.js?efeb:578
>
> [Vue warn]: Property or method "books" is not
> defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that
> this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for
> class-based components, by initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

The relevant blocks are below.  Here's the template loop for displaying the retrieved data:

```html
<tr v-for="(book, key) in books" v-bind:key="key">
    <td>
        {{book.title}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

In the script section:

```js
  import Firebase from 'firebase'

  let config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "https://...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
  };
  
  let app = Firebase.initializeApp(config)
  let db = app.database()
  let booksRef = db.ref('books/')

  /* was
  export default {
    name: 'app',
    firebase: {
      books: booksRef
    },
  */
        
  export default {
    name: 'app',
    firebase: function () {
        return {
            books: db.ref('books/')
        }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        newBook: {
          title: '',
          author: '',
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      addBook: function() {
        // code here
      },
      removeBook: function(book) {
        // code here
      }
    }
  }
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since Vue doesn’t allow dynamically adding root-level reactive properties, you have to initialize Vue instances by declaring all root-level reactive data properties upfront, even with an empty value:

```
data () {
  return {
    newBook: {
      title: '',
      author: '',
    },
    books: '',
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

from the [vuefire docs](https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire):

> If you need to access properties from the Vue instance, use the function syntax:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  firebase: function () {
    return {
      anArray: db.ref('url/to/my/collection/')
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Your advice sounds right but I'm still getting the same error.  I will edit the sample above to show what I have now.

Comment: Hmm, sorry! :/ Do you import VueFire and then Vue.use(VueFire) in main.js?

Comment: I am not using VueFire.  I could investigate adding it but I think I might be better off looking for a tutorial that works (or giving up and going back to React).

Comment: @P.H. what do you mean with "a tutorial that works"? The one you've linked makes use of it, and if you aren't using it then that's probably the issue you are facing.

Comment: @P.H. Ok, that could be the reason then. Just install, import and use it like in the tutorial. The firebase object gets used by vuefire. Without it isn’t useful.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  I don't see anyone else hopping into the discussion!

Comment: @P.H. You're welcome :) Have you tested it with vuefire now?

Comment: Did you get it working now? Would be good to update here to point to the right solution. If it was just the missing dependency we should mention it :)